# Axes looking strange when exporting MATLAB figure to eps

Tags: matlab, export, axes, eps

I need help with getting rid of an exporting issue in Matlab.

When I export a MATLAB figure to eps format using the print command I get that the axes are looking strange in the new format and that the text that I added in the figure has moved.

[image]

I have tried to set different paper orientation, papersize and paperposition as well as changing the font and fontsize, but none of it seems to work.

Anyone that has an idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is your Matlab Release ? What is your OS ? Can you post an image of what's wrong somewhere on the web and provide a link ?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 and using Matlab 64 bit version 8.1.0.604 (R2013a). Can you see the picture here? http://postimg.org/image/zc44r59zz/6e7c1d00/

Thanks!

Comment: Use FEX submission `export_fig` for saving plots. It works way better than Matlabs inbuilt. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Comment: Maybe export_fig would solve the issue. I tried it before and realized that I needed to install Ghostscript. I was hoping that there would be another way to deal with this issue, since installing this program would take me through quite a tedious security process.